# C# compiler expecting closing curly brace

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, curly-braces

Can anyone please point out the cause of this error in the C# code of an ASP.Net application.
The build error is expecting a closing curly brace, although I have checked for all semicolons and brackets, but could not exactly pinpoint it. Any leads will be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code followed by the screen shot.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


    namespace ANTrack
    {
        public class MyObjDataSource
        {
            public int iCount;
            public string strName;

            public void GetIncident(int IncidentID)
            {
                private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Closing Curly Brace Error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it has to do with the line:

```
 private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

You don't want to put a `private` in front of that, it's a variable in a method.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it. I guess I have to do more reading on C# :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void GetIncident(int IncidentID)
{
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
}
```

Remove `private` from variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


    namespace ANTrack
    {
        public class MyObjDataSource
        {
            public int iCount;
            public string strName;

            public void GetIncident(int IncidentID)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not declare access modifiers like `private` in method, remove it